# play framework (java) : view include another view with a map

Tags: view, playframework, include, arguments

I have this view:

**Profile.scala.html :**

```
 @(message: String)

    @Main("Welcome") {
        Welcome : @message
        <br>
        <h2>Profile</h2><br>
        <a href="#">Edit Profile</a><br>
        <a href="@routes.Application.viewEnvironments()">Your Environments</a>

        **@ViewEnvironment.scala.html ????? how can I include it ?**


    }
```

and I want to include in it, another view (this one):

**ViewEnvironment.scala.html:**

```
@(map: Map[String, String])

<h2> Environments :</h2>
<p><a href="@routes.Application.AddEnvironment()"> Add new Environment</a></p>

@for((k,v)<- map){

<a href = "#">View: @v</a><br>
<a href="@routes.Application.editEnv(k)">Edit : @v</a><br>
}

<br>
```

... Can I do that?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are [just functions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Includes), so if you have a template file in `app/views/ViewEnvironment.scala.html` it will be compiled to a function you can call as `@views.html.ViewEnvironment(envMap)`.

If the template you're calling from is in the same package, e.g. `views.{type-suffix}` you can omit the full qualification and just call it as:

```
@(message: String)

    @Main("Welcome") {
        Welcome : @message
        <br>
        <h2>Profile</h2><br>
        <a href="#">Edit Profile</a><br>
        <a href="@routes.Application.viewEnvironments()">Your Environments</a>

        @ViewEnvironment(
            Map(
                "key1" -> "value1",
                "key2" -> "value2"
            )
        )
    }
}
```